# Rspec and Rails 4, update skip callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I try to run an update test with rspec for my rails application.

I'm using rspec 3.5 and rails 4.

The behaviour is supposed to be the following :

When i create a new service with a selling price, it's create a Price instance and set the relation with the service. Then, when i update my service, if there is no selling price, it's destroy the price record (requirement of the client to save space in database).
The process i implemented seems to be working fine, when i test with the UI and i check the count of Price record, it's decrease by one like it's suppose. However, the unit test if failing.

Here is the code :

Service Controller :

```
  def update
    @service.assign_attributes(service_params)

    puts "update method"

    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.valid?
        if params['preview']
          @service.build_previews
          format.js { render 'services/preview' }
        else
          @service.save!
          format.html { redirect_to client_trip_days_path(@client, @trip), notice: t('flash.services.update.notice') }
        end
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.js { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

The callback in the Service model :

```
  def create_or_update_price
    puts "in create or update price"
    if selling_price.present? && price.present?
      self.price.update_columns(:trip_id => trip.id, :currency => trip.client.currency, :purchase_price => purchase_price, :selling_price => selling_price)
    elsif selling_price.present? && !price.present?
      self.price = RegularPrice.create(:trip => trip, :currency => trip.client.currency, :purchase_price => purchase_price, :selling_price => selling_price)
    elsif !selling_price.present? && price.present?
      self.price.destroy
    end
  end
```

The test :

```
it "updates the lodging and destroy the price" do
    puts "nombre de service avant création : "
    puts Service.count
    puts "nombre de prix avant création : "
    puts Price.count
    lodging = FactoryGirl.create(:lodging_service, selling_price: 200)
    puts "nombre de service après création : "
    puts Service.count
    puts "nombre de prix après création : "
    puts Price.count
    expect(lodging.reload.price).to be_present
    puts "nombre de prix avant update : "
    puts Price.count
    puts "id"
    puts lodging.id
    patch :update, client_id: client.id, trip_id: trip.id, id: lodging.to_param, service: valid_attributes_no_more_price
    # patch :update, client_id: client.id, trip_id: trip.id, id: lodging.id, service: valid_attributes_with_price
    puts "nombre de prix après update : "
    puts Price.count
    # expect{
    #   patch :update, client_id: client.id, trip_id: trip.id, id: lodging.id, service: valid_attributes_no_more_price
    # }.to change(RegularPrice, :count).by(0)
    expect(lodging.reload.price).to be_nil
  end

  let(:valid_attributes_no_more_price) {
attributes_for(:lodging_service, trip: trip, selling_price: "")
```

}

As you can see, there is a lot of puts since i try to find what is wrong.

The output is :
nombre de service avant création :
0
nombre de prix avant création :
0
in create or update price
nombre de service après création :
1
nombre de prix après création :
1
nombre de prix avant update :
1
id
10
nombre de prix après update :
1

Failure/Error: expect(lodging.reload.price).to be_nil

```
   expected: nil
        got: #<RegularPrice id: 2, label: nil, currency: "CHF", selling_price: 200.0, priceable_type: "Service", p...ated_at: "2017-07-13 08:08:47", quantity: 1, type: "RegularPrice", position: 1, purchase_price: nil>
```

As we can see, it's look like the callback is not fired after the update, and the action in the controller is not reached.

Have you any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks :)

PS: I always have trouble to include code in my questions, is there a tutorial on how to make it?

Comment: For the tutorial, when you ask or answer a question, there's a '?' icon in the upper right (on the toolbar) of the editor, if you click it there's some quick help you can look at and an 'advanced help' link, have you looked through and read those?

Comment: Did you manage to fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not mentioned your ruby version I'll assume it's 2.

First of all you need to learn how to properly debug your code in order to fix the issues yourself.

Here is what you have to do:

1.Add `pry` gem to your app, [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) there is also a version for ruby 1.9.3.

2.Add a break point in your code

```
it "updates the lodging and destroy the price" do
  (...) # Code here.

  binding.pry # The debugger  will open a console at this point   

  (...) # Maybe more code here
end
```

3.Verify all the variable and their values and see where the problem lies

In case you could not find the issue with `binding.pry` in your rspec file before the expect add it to after the first line of the method, and you can step through the debugger by typing `next` in the console opened by pry (it will be where your rails server is runnig).
If that still does not help, try and add a `binding.pry` in your classes and see what is the state in there.

Spend a few minutes/hours now to learn debugging and it will save you days/weeks in long term. (while you are learning you don't really know how a program should behave and that extra knowledge is priceless, after a while you only need a debugger for extremely complicated issues).

Comment: I follow your explications, but the bug is still here.
When i use binding.pry in the rspec file, the variables are all goods.
When i put it in the update methode of the controller, it does nothing.
When i put it in the model, it raise at the creation but not at the update.

The problem seems to be that the patch :update does not go to the update methode of the controller
Is there a way to display all the url request made by rspec?

Thanks for helping

Comment: I don't know if there is a command, but if you add a binding.pry before `patch:` you will be able to inter in the pry console ind there and do a `step` which will take you inside the request, and there you could do `next` and user `self` etc to get more info.

Comment: Also, I would recommend you try and add debugging points in all the methods of your controller to see which one will be hit. I don't know why your update method is not hit, did you add the `binding.pry` as the first line in the method?