# Spree CVV not being sent to payment merchant

Tags: ruby, spree

I am using spree version 3.0.8 with active merchant with moneris as the payment gateway. When I talk to moneris they are not receiving any cvv from spree everything I check in the documentation says the cvv is passed automatically any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at your code and see where if the cvv field is set at all or if something happens along the way with it.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45077040/3757435) to help you debug your program.

You also need to add more details to your question (like parts of the code that is relevant) in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Thats the issue its not my code its spree ruby gem with active merchant when I debug the logs and payment the cvv is saved as part of the order. The spree processing gem contains the following code.